# Symfony Overblog использовать context

Tags: symfony, symfony4, graphql

в спецификации graphql есть понятие context

возможно ли его передавать с клиента и потом использовать в резолвере

речь про https://github.com/overblog/GraphQLBundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в целом это возможно только в резолвере

https://github.com/overblog/GraphQLBundle/issues/617#issuecomment-557519302